# My Mac Pro fans completely refuse to speed up

Tags: performance, mac-pro, temperature

I recently purchased this 4,1 Mac Pro in pristine condition. Only issue is, none of the fans will speed up under heavy load. The temps can go up to 90°C and none of them speed up. I can manually speed them up, but that’s about it. Already reset SMC, PRAM and tried my troubleshooting booting from the secondary hard drive on which lays a clean OS X that got installed using this Mac Pro, since I took the main hard drive out of my iMac (thought maybe OS X installations are hardware-specific). I could just keep using MacsFanControl, but I rather have the underlying issue fixed.

Clue: I read somewhere online that somebody had the opposite issue, their Mac would ramp the fans up all the way. Said person found out that a parameter in their firmware was set to the maximum fan speed (rpm) where it should define the minimum.

I’m out of ideas.

Comment: Are you watching the fan speed or just listening for fans? Even under full load, my Mac Pro (2009, 5,1 firmware, 2x 3.46 Ghz Hex-core) doesn't really get fan speed up. The Tdiode temps read 90 C and the booster fans get up to about 2000, 2300 rpm maybe if it's warm in the room, but the audible difference is negligible. Edit: Also, OS X installations are never hardware specific (although after installation, an NVRAM and SMC doesn't hurt)

Comment: @NoahL - Interesting, my booster fans run at about 3k rpm even with the TDiodes at 60°C & I can always hear it [similar machine, ex-4,1 with 2x6-core 3.46]. My older 3,1 essentially runs silent unless pushed really hard. Saren - is it still a 4,1 or was it firmware upgraded to 5,1 - About this Mac > System Report, 1st page, Hardware overview, will say MacPro4,1 or 5,1

Comment: @NoahL Mine got the original firmware, but even when my CPU A core is at 90 C, it won’t spin up the fans. What’s odd to me is that after a while those fan speeds should fluctuate, go up and down a bit as the temps change, especially in a stress test where it’s all getting pretty hot. But mine stay at the absolute minimum, just sometimes going up and down by 1rpm. Apple Care was ofc as helpful as nothing… the single CPU model apparently takes longer to speed up. Also I’m scared to go 40C above the designed CPU temps. My XEON CPu was designed für 67C, I cannot run at 100 for a reaction.

Comment: Absolute minimum being 1500 rpm for your boosters? If you're concerned about temperature, I'd just manually push the fans up. You shouldn't get that hot unless you're doing batch processing or rendering or something that you know will push the CPU. I just googled the max temp for my CPU and found it was 78 C, which means that I have run the CPU at ~12 C above maximum operating temperature constantly for 40+ hours straight (batch ffmpeg processes).

Comment: This thread suggests using Macs Fan Control or a similar program to create custom rules for fan speed: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/xeon-x5690-temperatures-and-fan-speed.1958060/

Comment: @NoahL I had rather gotten at the root of this and I’m not the kinda guy for patch work kinda fixes. But I found out that my terminal based stress test, also made the temps show up higher than they actually were, because once I stopped it the temps would drop by 20C in an instant. But even then I feel like Apple runs them way hotter than the design capacities. I guess Apple wants to ruin our hardware while also letting us think their machine are so quiet.. I don’t like how MacsFanControl doesn’t consider all the sensors at once (dangerous! PSU!)